# Sticky header that hides on scroll down + fixed progress bar

Tags: javascript, css

Trying to create a header + progress bar like this:
https://blog.fullstory.com/cross-functional-collaboration/

1. Need a sticky (fixed) header that only shows up when you scroll up, and hides when you scroll down.
2. There is a progress bar fixed below the header at all times. 
   When you scroll up and the blue header is hidden, the progress bar should still show...just like blog.fullstory.com

https://codepen.io/connecteev/pen/eaqxvj

Code Snippet:

```js
// Hide Header on scroll down, Show Header on scroll up
var didScroll;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 5;
var navbarHeight = $('header').outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function(event){
    didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
    if (didScroll) {
        hasScrolled();
        didScroll = false;
    }
}, 250);

function hasScrolled() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();

    // Make sure they scroll more than delta
    if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
        return;

    // If they scrolled down and are past the navbar, add class .nav-up.
    // This is necessary so you never see what is "behind" the navbar.
    if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight){
        // Scroll Down
        $('header').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');
    } else {
        // Scroll Up
        if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
            $('header').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
        }
    }
    lastScrollTop = st;
}
```

```css
body {
    /* this is to make room for the top nav / header */
    padding-top: 60px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  transition: top 0.8s ease-in-out;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
  height: 30px;
}

/* smooth position indicator */
.scroll-progress-bar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 3px;
  width: 0;
  background: green;
  color: green;
  z-index: 2;
}

.nav-up {
    /* hide the top nav on scroll down */
    top: -300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="tw-z-50">
  <div class="nav-down">
  </div>
  <div class="tw-w-full">
    <div class="scroll-progress-bar"></div>
  </div>
</header>

<div>This is a test</div><div>This is a test</div><div>This is a test</div><div>This is a test</div><div>This is a test</div><div>This is a test</div><div>This is a test</div><div>This is a test</div><div>This is a test</div><div>This is a test</div><div>This is a test</div><div>This is a test</div><div>This is a test</div><div>This is a test</div><div>This is a test</div><div>This is a test</div><div>This is a test</div><div>This is a test</div>
```

I am trying to get this to work.
Any ideas?

Comment: It seems to work fine on Chrome 74, Mac OS.

Comment: Consider adding a *runnable* [mcve] to your question. It would make it easier for others to help you. Not adding one and suggesting the answer should contain one is likely to be considered inappropriate, if not disrespectful.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I have updated the description with a minimal reproducible example. Ideas?

Comment: I can help with the progress bar. By placing the progress bar inside the header, but making that header not disappear completely it's leaving only the lower pixels visible. This way you will get a result similar to your example. I will add some code as an answer soon.

Comment: In the end it took me more time than expected, this all related to the throttling and different not so exact results in different Browsers from that. Your question made me learn something new too. If my answer is a final answer for you then mark it ✅. So others with the same thoughts can see this question was answered.

Comment: Furthermore there is one more related topic. The provided code only works well for a header on a total page. Now what if you want this same effect inside a mini viewport, that's only a segment of the page? Has the same logic, but it needs more script.

Comment: @2x2p done. Thank you so much for the help! To you and ICE as well!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had to start from scratch and removed JQuery to make it more readable, feel free to use this code or parts of it. You can always add JQuery again if you like.

A test is running live here http://testing.2x2p.com/header/

This concept so far works in Firefox, Safari and Chrome. Also works on iPhone and iPad. Looking forward to hear from you guys what it does on Android devices.

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sticky Header with progress-Bar Document</title>
    <style type="text/css">
     #header-wrap {
         position:fixed;
         margin: 0;
         top:0px;
         left:0;
         background-color: blue;
         min-height: 80px;
         width:100%;
         transition: top 666ms;
     }
     #header-content {
         margin: 0;
         padding: 10px;
         background-color: lightblue;
         min-height: 75px;
         box-sizing:border-box;
     }
     #header-progress {
         padding:0px;
         box-sizing:border-box;
         background-color: red;
         height: 5px;
         width: 0%;
         overflow:hidden;
         transition: width 333ms linear;
     }
     #page-content {
         margin-top:80px;
         padding:5px;
         box-sizing:border-box;
         background-color: white;
         width: 100%;
         overflow:scroll;
     }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="header-wrap">
     <div id="header-content">
       Header bla bla bla..
     </div>
     <div id="header-progress">
      &nbsp;
     </div>
    </div>
    <div id="page-content">
      <h3>Body text 1 </h3>
        This is a test<br>
        This is a test<br>
        This is a test<br>
        This is a test<br>
        This is a test<br>
        This is a test<br>
        This is a test<br>
        This is a test<br>
        This is a test<br>
        This is a test<br>
        This is a test<br>
        This is a test<br>
        This is a test<br>
        This is a test<br>
        This is a test<br>
        This is a test<br>
        This is a test<br><br>
      <h3>Body text 2 </h3>
        This is a test<br>
        This is a test<br>
        This is a test<br>
        This is a test<br>
        This is a test<br>
        This is a test<br>
        This is a test<br>
        This is a test<br>
        This is a test<br>
        This is a test<br>
        This is a test<br>
        This is a test<br>
        This is a test<br>
        This is a test<br>
        This is a test<br>
        This is a test<br>
        This is a test<br>
        This is a test<br>
       <h3>Body text 3 </h3>
        This is a test<br>
        This is a test<br>
        This is a test<br>
        This is a test<br>
        This is a test<br>
        This is a test<br>
        This is a test<br>
        This is a test<br>
        This is a test<br>
        This is a test<br>
        This is a test<br>
        This is a test<br>
        This is a test<br>
        This is a test<br>
        This is a test<br>
        This is a test<br>
        This is a test<br>
        This is a test<br>
    </div>
    </body>
    <script language="javascript">
    
        window.prevOffset = 0;
        var smartScrollThrottle = 0;
        const smartScrollHeader = document.getElementById('header-wrap');
        const smartProgressBar = document.getElementById('header-progress');
        const smartScrollPage = document.getElementById('page-content');
        
        var smartScroll = function () {
                    
            if(new Date().getTime()-smartScrollThrottle<200){
                //console.log('smartScrollThrottle is active',smartScrollThrottle);
                return false;
            }
            // reset throttle after minimum of 200ms, allows smartScroll only 5 times per second
            smartScrollThrottle = (new Date()).getTime();
            
            var tempOffset = window.pageYOffset;
            //console.log('tempOffset', tempOffset);
            //console.log('prevOffset', window.prevOffset);
            
            if(tempOffset > (window.prevOffset+25) || tempOffset < 100){
                // hide 75 pixels from the total 80 px 
                smartScrollHeader.style.top = '-75px';
            }
            if(tempOffset < (window.prevOffset-25) || tempOffset < 75){
                // show all 80 pixels
                smartScrollHeader.style.top = '0px';
            }
            
            // update the prevOffset value for the next scroll event
            window.prevOffset = window.pageYOffset;
            //console.log('scrollHeight', smartScrollPage.scrollHeight);
            
            // reuse tempOffset value but now for the progress-bar as percentage
            tempOffset = (tempOffset)/(document.documentElement.scrollHeight-(window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight));
            //console.log('Scroll percentage', tempOffset);
            if(tempOffset<0){tempOffset=0;}
            if(tempOffset>1){tempOffset=1;}
            smartProgressBar.style.width = Math.round(tempOffset*100)+"%";

            // Chrome and Firefox do not send scroll events when the pages bottom is reached, so we must fix it
             setTimeout(smartScroll, 333); // just trigger one more smartScroll event 333ms after the last browser event

        } // end of smartScroll
        
        window.addEventListener('scroll', smartScroll);
        smartScroll(); // init the progress bar on page refresh
        
    </script>
    </html>
```

Comment: Mobile Safari 12 on the iPad somehow shows the header again when at absolute bottom of the scrolling page. This is in fact a nice feature, but not originally intended :-)

Comment: I believe we can get even more consistent results if you make the `DIV` with ID `page-content` a fixed element with a height set to height of the viewport and do the scrolling on internal HTML of the `DIV` instead of the entire page. This requires a complete revision of the code `documentElement.scrollHeight-documentElement.clientHeight`.

Comment: The problem in Chrome and Firefox is not coming from wrong mathematics, it's caused by the throttle that cancels the last event when reaching the end.

Comment: @ICE it's now all fixed and runs smooth in Chrome, Firefox and Safari. Let me know if you find other bugs.

Comment: thank you for this! This is very similar to ICE 's solution....though yours seems to work on Safari as well. Upvoted :)

Comment: if you want to play with having the header stick on screen a bit longer fiddle with this `window.prevOffset+25) || tempOffset < 100` and maybe you want to change the main transition speed of `666ms`. For me `1s` seems slow and `500ms` was too fast. The progress bar has a transition half the speed of the first one. It could be faster but better not less than the throttle timer now set to `200ms`, same goes for the last `setTimeout(smartScroll, 333);` –

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with pure JavaScript, No need for jQuery.

You can fill the content and have any height you want. With JavaScript you can calculate the height of the top element.

Since the progress bar is outside of the `top`, you can move the `top` to the `-Height` and still have the progress bar in the view.

```js
var lastpos = 0;

document.addEventListener('scroll',function(){
  
 let pos = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
 let windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight || window.innerHeight;
 let sHeight = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
 let pWidth = ((pos/(sHeight-windowHeight))*100);
  
 let top = document.getElementById('top');
 let percent = document.getElementById('percent');
  
 if (pos>top.clientHeight && (pos>=sHeight-windowHeight-100 || lastpos<=pos)){
  top.style.top = (-top.clientHeight)+'px';
 }else{
  top.style.top = 0;
 }
  
 percent.style.width = Math.ceil(pWidth)+'%';

    lastpos = pos;
  
},true);
```

```css
*{ padding: 0; margin: 0;}

#top{
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #2E7CFF;
 height: inherit;
}

.progress{
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
}

#percent{
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 bottom: -3px;
 height: 3px;
 width: 0;
 background-color: #FF2E7F;
}

#top{
 transition: all ease-in-out 0.8s;
}

#percent{
 transition: all ease-in-out 0.1s;
}

.content{
    height: 4000px;
    padding-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="top">
 <div>
  Some Content for header
  <br>
  another line
 </div>
 <div class="progress">
  <div id="percent"></div>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="content">Content Inside the Page</div>
```

Comment: The whole point of that header's UX is: it's ***always at hand*** by scrolling a bit up but you can hide it by scrolling down, to get the extra screen real estate. You seem to have missed it.

Comment: @ICE amazing, this works great.....and also, you removed jQuery for me! Huge thanks.

Comment: @ICE Chrome looks great but I just noticed that this doesn't work on Safari at all...the progress bar doesn't show up. Any ideas...I noticed you mentioned Safari in 
 2x2p 's solution below...does this work for you on Safari?

Comment: @ICE thanks, but there's no error in Safari's console.

Comment: @ICE thanks! This last edit works great. It's cleaner than the other solution imo....but there's a bug (on safari only) where the header shows up when you've navigated all the way to the bottom of the page. On Chrome and Firefox that does not happen and it works fine.

Comment: @ICE this is what the console.log shows on scroll down on safari: ```[Log] 5001>60&&5000<=5001 (call-me, line 112)
[Log] 5014>60&&5015<=5014 (call-me, line 112)
[Log] 5011>60&&5014<=5011 (call-me, line 112)
[Log] 5008>60&&5011<=5008 (call-me, line 112)
[Log] 5006>60&&5008<=5006 (call-me, line 112)
[Log] 5004>60&&5006<=5004 (call-me, line 112)
[Log] 5003>60&&5004<=5003 (call-me, line 112)
[Log] 5002>60&&5003<=5002 (call-me, line 112)
[Log] 5001>60&&5002<=5001 (call-me, line 112)
[Log] 5000>60&&5001<=5000 (call-me, line 112)```

Comment: @kp123 I've changed only that `if` condition in the last edit. Hope it works. `100` means at the end of page at last `100px` scroll top not working. play with it, make it shorter and see how it works in Safari. for example try it with `100` first. if it worked, make it shorter like `50` or `30`.

Comment: @ICE check out my last answer I just posted, that builds on what you've done without needing the variable...works in Safari too.

Answer (score 2):

BUilding on @ICE 's answer, this works cross-browser:

```
    var lastpos = 0;
    document.addEventListener('scroll',function() {
      let pos = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop; // use window.pageYOffset?
      let windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight || window.innerHeight;
      let sHeight = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
      let maxScrollHeight = sHeight-windowHeight;
      if (pos >= maxScrollHeight) {
        pos = maxScrollHeight;
      }
      let pWidth = ((pos/maxScrollHeight)*100);

      let top = document.getElementById('top');
      let percent = document.getElementById('percent');

      if (pos>top.clientHeight && lastpos<=pos) {
        top.style.top = (-top.clientHeight)+'px';
      } else {
        top.style.top = 0;
      }
      percent.style.width = Math.ceil(pWidth)+'%';
      lastpos = pos;

    },true);
```